# is there alternative way to open facebook on flutter app than Web view?

Tags: webview, flutter-facebook-login

i have flutter facebook downloader app which have facebook web view function and copy past feature to downloadvideos from facebook. unfortunatly Google sent message to change this feature.

is there any alternative way to let the user login to facebook on my app and to get access facebook ?

email warning which is sent from google is here i attached ..

*> We are writing to follow up again on our below e-mails.  We see that

> your “Downloader for Facebook” app remains available in the Google
> Play store, despite violating Google Play’s policies against webview
> apps and against apps that allow or encourage users to download
> copyrighted content without authorization, and despite not having our
> client’s permission to provide a webview of the Facebook website from
> within your app.
>
> Accordingly, we request that you confirm your intent to comply with
> our clients’ requests to (1) remove your  app  copy/paste download
> functionality in the future.*

any help is appreciated. Thank you.